# Crystal reports on Windows Azure is not getting displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, azure

I have written an web application in VS2010 ASP.net C#, to display Crystal reports. 
I moved this application to Azure Emulator. It was working fine locally. However after deploying it with Azure, crystal report is not getting displayed and not even an exception is thrown.

I have installed

1. Installed CRforVS_13_0.exe
2. Then installed CRRuntime_64bit_13_0, on my machine sequentially.

Any input from any1 will be helpful. Please let know if you want more information.

Thanks,
Tanuja

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its not supported on Azure till now.

Comment: Note to others reading this: This is *NOT* the correct answer. It *IS* possible - please see my answer for details

Answer (score 5):

You **definitely** can do it. I have done it myself and even wrote a step by step [blog post about running Crystal Reports on Azure](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html).

It revolves around creating a start up task to run a crystal reports installation file on your new Azure web role instances. There are plenty of snags which I have listed so give it a try. It **does** work!

Comment: Your procedure is working, but i face the following problem: msi installs Aspnet_Client folder in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_clientbut Azure puts my application in E:\sitesroot\0. So, many files are not served (crv.js) causing Javascript errors (bobj is not defined). How have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I just copied that whole folder and put it in the solution

Comment: Yes, what I were going to do.. first on StartUp.cmd -> robocopy D:\inetpub\wwwroot E:\sitesroot\0 /S [not work properly: msiexec exits BEFORE CR is installed] then putting all files inside Web Application

Please update your blog post for future users!

Comment: Another suggestion: to speed up deployment process could be useful to download CR Installer instead of putting it in the bin. I put a line in StartUp.cmd http://superuser.com/a/59489/113303

Comment: I meant that I copy and pasted the aspnet_client folder into my solution and *then* deployed it. It wasn't in my startup task. Although your way is probably neater. Interesting suggestion... I have experimented with using BootStrapper to download this installation file from my blob storage but I just couldn't get it to work

Comment: Yes, in second attempt I too pasted into solution before deploy. This my actual StartUp (download from storage not allowed, but from Business Objects works) 1) cscript.exe downloadfile.vbs    2) unzip CRRuntime_64bit_13_0.zip   3) msiexec.exe /I "CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_2\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi" /qn.   downloadfile.vbs and unzip.exe in my solution, too.

Comment: have you ever experienced Unhealthy Deployment? Reason: "Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" but Runtime Engine is installed, Website and Reports are working!!

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the same problem of getting Crystal Reports 2010 (13.0.4) working on Azure. I followed the advice of [BritishDeveloper](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html) and some other sources. My method differs only slightly in that I used Azure blob storage to store the crystal runtime which makes project publishing a lot faster than when including it within your project.

Here's how I got crystal reports working:

**1) Set up a new blob storage service within [Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspace/StorageExtension/storage)**

**2) Upload the Crystal installer to this blob storage**

Using the free tool [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) upload [CRRuntime_64bit_13_9_4.msi](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) into a container called *crystalinstaller* (remember to unzip before uploading).

**3) In Visual Studio create a startup script definition in your Azure project ServiceDefinition.csdef:**

```
<ServiceDefinition...>
  <WebRole...>
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="AzureStartUp.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
    </Startup>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

**4) Store the following startup script in the root of your web project with 'build action' *none* and 'copy to output' set to *always*. Lesson learnt here: the approot/siteroots isn't always on E: drive**

```
@ECHO off
@REM Setting up Azure Stroage Credentials
set azurestoragename=<name>
set azurestoragekey=<key>
set storagecontainername=crystalinstaller

@REM Setting up Azure Drive 
@REM (sometimes E:, sometimes F: maybe one day G:?)
set drive=%cd:~0,3%

@REM Download Crystal Runtime 13.0.4
@REM from blob storage account
set filename=CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_4.msi
AzureBlobDownloader.exe "%azurestoragename%" "%azurestoragekey%" "%storagecontainername%" "%filename%"

@REM Install Crystal Runtime 13.0.4
msiexec.exe /I CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_4.msi /qn

@REM Copy Crystal Reports Viewer Files
robocopy D:\inetpub\wwwroot %drive%sitesroot\0 /S
robocopy D:\inetpub\wwwroot %drive%approot /S
```

**5) Download a command line tool that can download from blob storage to your azure service VM**
I used packagedownloader.exe from [Windows Azure Tomcat Solution](http://tomcatazure.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) but there are probably others or you could easily roll-your-own. I renamed this to AzureBlobDownloader.exe and copied along with the included Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll into the root of my web project again with 'build action' *none* and 'copy to output' set to *always*.

If you're still having trouble try to remote desktop into your instance and use a tool like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to monitor what's happening.

Comment: I need to deploy the Cloud Service or the web app project?

Answer (score 1):

First create a folder in your solution named for example 'assets'
Copy CRRuntime_64bit_13_0.msi in this folder.
Then put the following code in your ServiceDefinition.csdef

`<Startup>
      <Task executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" commandLine="assets/CRRuntime_64bit_13_0.msi"></Task>
</Startup>`

This way you install the crystal runtime on the cloud server before loading your application.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: NO, it does not work out. I tried it on Azure emulator. On emulator it was giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible; we host a SL app in Azure with a report server running in an Azure VM (still in beta, we've had some connectivity problems, but pretty satisfied for a beta product). The report server runs via Windows service, and we have an installation file that handles installing the CR runtime and our service. The service then polls our db for pending report requests, then processes them as needed.

We run all of our reports as PDF, so the user simply downloads the PDF. If you're having problems displaying the report directly, you might investigate this alternative; it's worked great for us.